# How to grab a text inside a div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to grab the text inside my `#address` div using JS. For some reason, I keep getting a `null` value. Please correct me if I did anything that I am not supposed to. Here is what I've tried:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var uri = "www. google.com";
  var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
  var address = document.getElementById("address");

  console.log(uri); // print out = www. google.com
  console.log(res); // print out = www.%20google.com
  console.log(address); // print out = null ????
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="address"> 410 Walker Street Lowell MA 01851</div>
<h1>console.log();</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Run</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting the DOMElement, but not retrieving the text from it. To do that use `innerText`. Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var uri = "www. google.com";
  var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
var address = document.getElementById("address").innerText; // note innerText here

  console.log(uri); // print out = www. google.com
  console.log(res); // print out = www.%20google.com
  console.log(address); // print out = null ????
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="address"> 410 Walker Street Lowell MA 01851</div>
<h1>console.log();</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Run</button>
```

Or alternatively, as you've tagged this question with jQuery:

```
var address = $('#address').text();
```

Also note that you've set `id="addess"` in the HTML, which appears to be a typo.

Comment: That would work too. It depends on if you want the markup inside the element too or just the text. OP only has text so it's moot here.

Comment: Doesn't work ! :( `var address = document.getElementById("address").innnerText;`

Comment: @evoque2015 seems ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0yupgop5/ can you provide an example which shows the problem.

Comment: @evoque2015 `innerHTML`, not `innerText`.

Comment: If `document.getElementById("address")` returns `null` then `document.getElementById("address").innerHTML` will raise an error.

Comment: @Prusse obviously... but seen as it's in OPs HTML it will work fine.

Comment: Guys `var address = document.getElementById("address").innnerHTML;` is also not work. `console.log(address);` = undefine.

Comment: And by `var address = document.getElementById("address");...console.log(address); // print out = null ????` it looks that him may have a typo some where in the original code.

Comment: @evoque2015 see the fiddle I posted - it works fine. Can you post your complete code which shows this issue as the code I have posted will work fine.

Comment: @evoque2015 Please read your code carefully and also pay attention when typing/copying code. Compilers are not humans. They will fail to understand your code if there is a typo.

Comment: Okay. It works now, when I just use this `var address = document.getElementById("address");`

Comment: But, it print out the whole thing `<div id="address"> 410 Walker Street Lowell MA 01851</div>` I don't want that.

Comment: I only want what inside which is this `410 Walker Street Lowell MA 01851`

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
var address = document.getElementById("address").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using jquery, then what about

```
$("#address").html()
```

**Edit**: You need to include jquery for this to work in your  tag.

Comment: If you see the code, he is ussing Javascript notation.

Comment: @WilfredoP Question is tagged jQuery too, although this answer would be better if it explained why the current code doesn't work instead of suggesting alternative code without explanation.

Comment: @GolezTrol Sure that's will work, but I think the answer is incomplete, because if the OP put this code on their project never will work, because he does not added the jQuery Lib, for example.

Comment: Also jQuery is not tagged here :)

Comment: @WilfredoP Poor argument. If someone uses jQuery they probably have it included or know how to do this. This answer just shows a single line of code. You could as well argue that it should have `<script>` tags or that the function result is not assigned to a variable. And yes, jQuery tag is removed now, but that's more due to OP making a mess of his question. I've deleted my own answer for that reason. A right answer can become wrong any second for a question like this.

Comment: The first line contains JQuery file, there fore s/he defintely using Jquery.

Answer (score -2):

If you import the jquery library you can do:

```
$('#address').text();  //get's the text
$('#address').text("some text"); //sets the text

$('#address').text("some text"+ $('#address').text());  //prepends
```